# mysql count non blank fields

Tags: mysql

In a table `members(id, contractid, a,b,c,d)` I need to count:

1. the number of members who have at least one of a,b,c,d>0
2. The number of rows with a>0, b>0 etc for a given contractid (the relation between contracts and members is one to many).

My goal is to display a chart (table) with grouped info on how many of the members have selected a, b, c and d in their contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the aggregate `SUM()` in conjunction with boolean tests that return 0 or 1, you can determine how many are filled in:

#### Number of members with at least one filled in:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM members
/* add up the boolean comparisons (which return 0 or 1) to find out if the total is > 0 */
WHERE ((a > 0) + (b > 0) + (c > 0) + (d > 0)) > 0
/* Actually that's overkill, and it could just be an OR chain */
/* WHERE a > 0 OR b > 0 OR c > 0 OR d > 0 */
```

#### Number per contract id

```
SELECT
  contractid,
  /* SUM() a 1 for each row in which the col is > 0 */
  SUM(CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_greater_than_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b_greater_than_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_greater_than_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN d > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d_greater_than_0
FROM members
GROUP BY contractid
```

MySQL allows you to shorten this since `(a > 0)` returns a 1 or 0, but this isn't portable to all other RDBMS:

```
SELECT
  contractid,
  /* SUM() a 1 for each row in which the col is > 0 */
  SUM(a > 0) AS a_greater_than_0,
  SUM(b > 0) AS b_greater_than_0,
  SUM(c > 0) AS c_greater_than_0,
  SUM(d > 0) AS d_greater_than_0
FROM members
GROUP BY contractid
```

Comment: Thanks, I comboned your 2 queries and got what I was looking for:


SELECT
  COUNT(*), contractid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
  SUM(CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c,
  SUM(CASE WHEN d > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d
FROM members
WHERE ((a > 0) + (b > 0) + (c > 0) + (d > 0)) > 0
GROUP BY contractid order by id desc

Answer (score 0):

1. `select count(id) from Members where (a>0 or b>0 or c>0 or d>0)`
2. `select contractid,count(id) from members group by contractid having a>0;`
   `select contractid,count(id) from members group by contractid having b>0;`